# Android CalendarProvider Events Color

Tags: android, colors, calendar

I'm most confused on how to use Colors in the Android CalendarProvider. I can add events alright, but when I try to insert one with a particular color, this preference seems to be ignored for the default calendar color (light blue).

I guess I'm not exactly sure on how colors are used. I wonder if someone could be so kind as to shed some light on the matter.

Meanwhile, here's my code (Event parameter is a custom class, I know the name gets confusing):

```
public long insert(Event event) throws ParseException{

    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
    eventValues.put("calendar_id", 1); 
    eventValues.put(Events.SYNC_DATA1, event.getId());
    eventValues.put(Events.TITLE, event.getTitle());
    eventValues.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, event.getTitle());
    eventValues.put(Events.EVENT_COLOR, Color.RED);
    eventValues.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/Rome");

    eventValues.put(Events.DTSTART, event.getStart().getTime());
    eventValues.put(Events.DTEND, event.getEnd().getTime());

    Uri eventUri = mContentResolver.insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true").appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMY").appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "accountType").build(), eventValues);
    return Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I guess I was burned out the other night. Yet, in case someone else ends up here, it's only fair to give a brief explanation on the Calendar->Events interaction as far as I got it.

Long story short: event colors depend upon the calendar you put them in. Why is there an events_color column if it gets overridden by the Calendar colour? I whish I knew.

So, once you set up your fancy syncadapter, user etc. you need to create a new calendar:

```
public long insertCalendar(EventType eventType) {

    Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMY");
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, eventType.getDescription());
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, eventType.getDescription());
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, Color.parseColor(eventType.getColor()));
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, true);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
    //cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_SYNC1, eventType.getId());

    calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMY")
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
        .build();

    Uri result = mContentResolver.insert(calUri, cv);
    return Long.parseLong(result.getLastPathSegment());
}
```

Please notice I'm putting a color in the CALENDAR_COLOR column, in this case I'm parsing something like #000000 into Color.BLACK. Also notice the value inside ACCOUNT_TYPE. From what I gathered there doesn't seem to be another way around this.

```
public long insert(Event event, long calendarID) throws ParseException {

    EventTypeDal adapter = new EventTypeDal();
    EventType et = adapter.GetEventTypeById(event.getFkEventType());

    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

    eventValues.put("calendar_id", calendarID); 
    //eventValues.put(Events.SYNC_DATA1, event.getId());
    eventValues.put(Events.TITLE, event.getTitle());
    eventValues.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, et.getDescription());

    eventValues.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/Rome");

    eventValues.put(Events.DTSTART, event.getStart().getTime());
    eventValues.put(Events.DTEND, event.getEnd().getTime());

    Uri eventUri = mContentResolver.insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true").appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMY").appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "accountType").build(), eventValues);
    return Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
}
```

Now I'm putting an event inside a calendar (calendarID param). This event will be displayed with the calendar's color.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Events.EVENT_COLOR_KEY instead of EVENT_COLOR (which is read-only). The value you use needs to be a COLOR_KEY from the [ColorsColumns table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.ColorsColumns.html) of type TYPE_EVENT.