# Changing default calendar event color

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar

I'm trying to insert an event with a different default color by doing something like this :

```
public static void addReminder(Context context, String title,
        String description) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
    intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_COLOR, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_belize_hole));
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

But the new Calendar page appear with the same red color (the default one). How can i change it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could change it by creating a new Calendar because the color are sorted by Calendars. Source and How To can be found here:
[Android CalendarProvider Events Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791178/android-calendarprovider-events-color)

**Edit:**
as the [stackoverflow-meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) suggests (thanks for the link kleopatra), I'll quote the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791178/android-calendarprovider-events-color) because that will prevent link-rot and is "immediately helpful to readers". It wouldn't make sense when I wrote that answer again by myself, or would it? I mean, my answer was just thought to show people the other answer...

So, the following is all a quote of Sphaso (I don't know how to format that as a quote containing code):

Well, I guess I was burned out the other night. Yet, in case someone else ends up here, it's only fair to give a brief explanation on the Calendar->Events interaction as far as I got it.

Long story short: event colors depend upon the calendar you put them in. Why is there an events_color column if it gets overridden by the Calendar colour? I whish I knew.

So, once you set up your fancy syncadapter, user etc. you need to create a new calendar:

```
public long insertCalendar(EventType eventType) {

    Uri calUri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMY");
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME, eventType.getDescription());
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME, eventType.getDescription());
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR, Color.parseColor(eventType.getColor()));
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL, CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_ACCESS_OWNER);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT, true);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE, 1);
    cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.SYNC_EVENTS, 1);
    //cv.put(CalendarContract.Calendars.CAL_SYNC1, eventType.getId());

    calUri = calUri.buildUpon()
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMY")
        .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, CalendarContract.ACCOUNT_TYPE_LOCAL)
        .build();

    Uri result = mContentResolver.insert(calUri, cv);
    return Long.parseLong(result.getLastPathSegment());
}
```

Please notice I'm putting a color in the CALENDAR_COLOR column, in this case I'm parsing something like #000000 into Color.BLACK. Also notice the value inside ACCOUNT_TYPE. From what I gathered there doesn't seem to be another way around this.

```
public long insert(Event event, long calendarID) throws ParseException {

    EventTypeDal adapter = new EventTypeDal();
    EventType et = adapter.GetEventTypeById(event.getFkEventType());

    ContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();

    eventValues.put("calendar_id", calendarID); 
    //eventValues.put(Events.SYNC_DATA1, event.getId());
    eventValues.put(Events.TITLE, event.getTitle());
    eventValues.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, et.getDescription());

    eventValues.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/Rome");

    eventValues.put(Events.DTSTART, event.getStart().getTime());
    eventValues.put(Events.DTEND, event.getEnd().getTime());

    Uri eventUri = mContentResolver.insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(android.provider.CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER,"true").appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, "DUMMY").appendQueryParameter(Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, "accountType").build(), eventValues);
    return Long.parseLong(eventUri.getLastPathSegment());
}
```

Now I'm putting an event inside a calendar (calendarID param). This event will be displayed with the calendar's color.

Comment: ok, thank you :) so is it ok like that or should I try to write a very similar solution by myself?

Comment: ahh ... didn't notice that the reference was to a post on stackoverflow, my bad ;-) The encouraged approach in such a case is to flag/vote the question as duplicate - which you can't yet (and I can't judge the content) So copying is acceptable, IMO, you could come back once you'll have the rep and flag the question.